# In SQL Server 2008R2 can I force a View to use objects within the user's default schema instead of the schema in which the View exists?

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2

A bit of background. I have a base application and most clients use it as standard. However some clients have small code and database customisations.
Each of these clients has their own branch and maintenance can be tricky.

I want to consolidate all these into a single database structure (not a single database - we aren't doing multi-tenancy) to enable upgrades to be applied in a much more uniform fashion.
I'm still at the proof of concept stage, but the route I was going down would be to have the standard objects stay in the schema they currently exist in (mostly dbo) and have the custom objects reside in a schema for each client.

For example, I could have dbo.users and client1.users which has some additional columns. If I set the default schema for the client to be "client1" then the following query

```
SELECT * FROM users
```

will return data from the client1 schema or the dbo schema depending on which login is connected.
This is absolutely perfect for what I'm trying to achieve.

The problem I'm running into is with Views.
I have many views which are in the dbo schema and refer to the Users table. No matter which user I connect to the database as, these views always select from dbo.users.

So I'm guessing the question I have is:
Can I prefix the tables in the view with some variable like "DEFAULT"? e.g.

```
SELECT u.username, u.email, a.level
FROM DEFAULT.users u INNER JOIN accessLevels a ON u.accessID = a.accessID
```

If this isn't possible and I'm totally barking up the wrong tree, do you have any suggestions as to how I can achieve what I'm setting out to do?

Many thanks.

Comment: It seems to me you would need a view created in each schema explicitly selecting from the correct schema. i.e. `client1.View1` is `select from client1.Table1`, and `dbo.View1` is `select from dbo.Table1`. Surely your views are also customised per client, not just your tables?

Comment: That's precisely the issue - if I have 40 views referencing the "users" table, I don't want to have to create a further 40 of those views for each client. That's a maintenance nightmare waiting to happen.

Comment: Don't you already have those 40 custom views defined in the client1 code branch of your database? I don't see how you can avoid defining the additional column, unless your views are `SELECT *`. Doesn't the additional column have some custom functionality that requires a differently coded view?

Comment: No in most cases, any customisation (additional columns etc) are for a very specific area of the application. The additional column in the users table might contain a token for authentication on a different system. There would be no need to access that column in every view throughout the system.

Answer (score 0):

Just reference the name of the schema in which the views reside...

Select a.*, b.*
from schema1.TABLEA A 
join schema2.TABLEB B on A.ID = B.ID